# Null characters between letter in string

Tags: php, vbscript

i have a problem using some php functions on a string i get from a file. When i read it in notepad++ it seems to have no spaces but when i echo in cmd there appear to be spaces between the letters, and if i capture that output in a file and read it with notepad++ those characters are red as a black NULL. How is that character expressed so i remove it.
I am including a [file](https://www.transferbigfiles.com/78c8b57d-e2e5-4db7-8256-55a02801734b?rid=gnS3_8bNKq8u7h_JDnnkNA2) since i cant write what happens here.
thank you in advance

PS the string was written in a file with vbscript btw

Comment: Can you add the PHP Code here ....

Comment: Are you allowed to modify the vbscript and then regenerate the file? If so, doing a string search and replace in your code on the vbNull type constant might take care of the issue.

Comment: Is it possible that the file is encoded in UTF-16? If so you'll need to open it as such. Parsing it as UTF-8 would lead to these NULLs

Comment: Yes, this file contains NULLs. Now, what's your question?

Comment: how do i remove them, through php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use str_replace:

```
$str = file_get_contents("out.txt"); 
$str = str_replace("\0", "", $str); 
file_put_contents("out1.txt", $str);
```

Comment: thnx "\0" was the name of the little bastard